# git post-receive hook and prevent tags pushing

Tags: git, git-post-receive

In my GIT's post-receive hook I need to avoid execution of some code if a tag is pushed.

I tried using the env variable $refname but it looks empty.

Any idea?

Thanks

Randomize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Post receive hook gets something like

```
refs/tag/FOO in case of tags and 
refs/heads/branch-foo in case of branches
```

based of tags Vs branches you can determine.

Answer (score 2):

`$rev_type` - where did you get the idea of an environment variable available like that?

The post-receive hooks gets input from its stdin in the form:

```
<oldrev> <newrev> <refname>
```

Read the refname from the stdin and see if it contains tags ( it will be something like `refs/tags/<tagname>` )

See here for reference: http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: sorry it was typo. I'm using "refname" but it is empty. Probably is the way I'm trying to read it from stdin: read refname; refname=$(read refname); refname=read refname; and so on